# Figure number is incrementing by 2 if subfigure is used

Tags: numbering, subfloats

```
\documentclass{svmult}

% choose options for [] as required from the list
% in the Reference Guide, Sect. 2.2

\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
                             % when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
% etc.
% see the list of further useful packages
% in the Reference Guide, Sects. 2.3, 3.1-3.3
\makeindex             

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure*}[t!]
\label{Flowchart}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=70 mm,height= 50 mm]{Flowchart_SMHI.pdf}
        \caption{(a)}
    \end{subfigure}%
    ~ 
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=70 mm,height= 50 mm]{Flowchart_FMLI.pdf}
        \caption{(b)}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Flowchart for SMHI and FMLI type of MBs}
\end{figure*}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

If this figure should appear as fig.2 in actual, due to use of subfigure it is showing fig 3.

Comment: Your document isn't compilable at all. There's no `\begin{document}` and the `figure*` environment is not needed here (since it's no two-column document)

Answer (score 3):

The `caption` package used with `svmult.cls` issues a warning

```
Package caption Warning: \caption will not be redefined since it's already
(caption)                redefined by a document class or package which is
(caption)                unknown to the caption package.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

More serious is the *error* message issued when `subcaption` is loaded:

```
! Package caption Error: The `subcaption' package does not work correctly
(caption)                in compatibility mode.

See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

This should make it clear that you ***cannot*** use `subcaption` with the class.

You can use `subfig`, with the `caption=false` option.

```
\documentclass{svmult}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\makeindex             

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[t!]
\centering

\hspace*{\fill}%
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{Flowchart_SMHI.pdf}}%
\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{Flowchart_FMLI.pdf}}%
\hfill

\caption{Flowchart for SMHI and FMLI type of MBs}\label{Flowchart}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Note that the label must go *after* the caption.

[image]